# Pandas pivot index level3 and change with columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I need help with one problem:

I've got a dataframe like:

```
               a    b    c
0   0   40   1.0  2.0  3.0
        50   4.0  5.0  6.0
    1   40   7.0  8.0  9.0
        50  10.0 11.0 12.0
1   0   40  13.0 14.0 15.0
        50  16.0 17.0 18.0
    1   40  19.0 20.0 21.0
        50  22.0 23.0 24.0
```

Now, I did some conversions (some of them are neccesary) and ive got something like

```
             a    b    c
(0,0,40)   1.0  2.0  3.0
(0,0,50)   4.0  5.0  6.0
(0,1,40)   7.0  8.0  9.0
(0,1,50)  10.0 11.0 12.0
(1,0,40)  13.0 14.0 15.0
(1,0,50)  16.0 17.0 18.0
(1,1,40)  19.0 20.0 21.0
(1,1,50)  22.0 23.0 24.0
```

'''
And i would like to pivot the last index (40 or 50) and changed with columns,  have something like:

```
            40     50
0   0  a   1.0    4.0
       b   2.0    5.0
       c   3.0    6.0
    1  a   7.0   10.0
       b   8.0   11.0
       c   9.0   12.0
1   0  a  13.0   16.0
       b  14.0   17.0
       c  15.0   18.0
    1  a  19.0   22.0
       b  20.0   23.0
       c  21.0   24.0
```

or with tuple form as index like:

```
  (0,0,a)  1.0   4.0
  (0,0,b)  2.0   5.0
  (0,0,c)  3.0   6.0
  (0,1,a)  7.0   10.0
  (0,1,b)  8.0   11.0
  (0,1,c)  9.0   12.0
  and so on
```

Thanks all of you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prosessing index filled with `tuple`s is problematic, need `MulitIndex`.

```
#input data
print (df)
               a     b     c
(0, 0, 40)   1.0   2.0   3.0
(0, 0, 50)   4.0   5.0   6.0
(0, 1, 40)   7.0   8.0   9.0
(0, 1, 50)  10.0  11.0  12.0
(1, 0, 40)  13.0  14.0  15.0
(1, 0, 50)  16.0  17.0  18.0
(1, 1, 40)  19.0  20.0  21.0
(1, 1, 50)  22.0  23.0  24.0
```

First convert values from tuples to `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
print (df)
           a     b     c
0 0 40   1.0   2.0   3.0
    50   4.0   5.0   6.0
  1 40   7.0   8.0   9.0
    50  10.0  11.0  12.0
1 0 40  13.0  14.0  15.0
    50  16.0  17.0  18.0
  1 40  19.0  20.0  21.0
    50  22.0  23.0  24.0
```

then [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.stack().unstack(level=2)
print (df)
         40    50
0 0 a   1.0   4.0
    b   2.0   5.0
    c   3.0   6.0
  1 a   7.0  10.0
    b   8.0  11.0
    c   9.0  12.0
1 0 a  13.0  16.0
    b  14.0  17.0
    c  15.0  18.0
  1 a  19.0  22.0
    b  20.0  23.0
    c  21.0  24.0
```

And last if necessary cobvert back to tuples:

```
df.index = df.index.map(tuple).tolist()
print (df)
             40    50
(0, 0, a)   1.0   4.0
(0, 0, b)   2.0   5.0
(0, 0, c)   3.0   6.0
(0, 1, a)   7.0  10.0
(0, 1, b)   8.0  11.0
(0, 1, c)   9.0  12.0
(1, 0, a)  13.0  16.0
(1, 0, b)  14.0  17.0
(1, 0, c)  15.0  18.0
(1, 1, a)  19.0  22.0
(1, 1, b)  20.0  23.0
(1, 1, c)  21.0  24.0
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, after that I need to referenced the 3rd element on tuple index. Tuple could be on index, or I can use "reset_index()", to have a column called "index". I tried ['index'][2] but it isnt works, do you know what I mean?

Comment: @AlbertoF - Yop, use `df.index.str[2]`

Comment: Thanks but itsn't works in my operation. Ive a different df, similar of example but with column names a, b, c (same of 3rd element of tuple), now im trying to sum all row but substract value of the column in this row with the same column name as this 3rd element of index tuple.     `df.apply(lambda row: sum(row[1:]) - row[row[index.str[2]]], 1)`,      but it doesnt work

Comment: @AlbertoF - Can you post new question?

Comment: yes, ive posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193511/dataframe-tuple-index-with-multiindex-and-substract-3rd-element-of-index, many thanks