# dataframe tuple index with multiIndex and substract 3rd element of index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe like:

```
    `           a    b    c
    (0,0,a)   1.0  2.0  3.0
    (0,0,b)   4.0  5.0  6.0
    (0,0,c)   7.0  8.0  9.0
    (0,1,a)  10.0 11.0 12.0
    (0,1,b)  13.0 14.0 15.0
    (0,1,c)  16.0 17.0 18.0
    (1,0,a)  19.0 20.0 21.0
    (1,0,b)  22.0 23.0 24.0
    (1,0,c)  26.0 27.0 28.0`
```

If is a multiindex df with 3 level, like tuple.
Now, i want to add a new column with sum of all row and substract the element of the column name = 3rd elemnt of index tuple, something like:

```
    `           a    b    c    new
    (0,0,a)   1.0  2.0  3.0    5.0
    (0,0,b)   4.0  5.0  6.0   10.0
    (0,0,c)   7.0  8.0  9.0   15.0
    (0,1,a)  10.0 11.0 12.0   23.0
    (0,1,b)  13.0 14.0 15.0   28.0
    (0,1,c)  16.0 17.0 18.0   33.0
    (1,0,a)  19.0 20.0 21.0   41.0
    (1,0,b)  22.0 23.0 24.0   46.0
    (1,0,c)  26.0 27.0 28.0   53.0`
```

I have the same df with single index and it works with:

```
    ` df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(row[1:]) - row[row['index'][2]],1)`
```

But now I need to change some columns and i need to pass to multiindex. What can I do? change to single index? How? or I can keep multiIndex on my df?

Thanks

Comment: Please create an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: Answer was edited with `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)` and then by `EDIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` per rows and subtract values extracted by [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with third values of tuples in index by `str[2]`:

```
print(df.columns) 
MultiIndex([('a',),
            ('b',),
            ('c',)],
           )

#convert one level DataFrame to simple Index
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
print(df.columns) 
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

df['new'] = df.sum(axis=1) - df.lookup(df.index, df.index.str[2])
print (df)
              a     b     c   new
(0, 0, a)   1.0   2.0   3.0   5.0
(0, 0, b)   4.0   5.0   6.0  10.0
(0, 0, c)   7.0   8.0   9.0  15.0
(0, 1, a)  10.0  11.0  12.0  23.0
(0, 1, b)  13.0  14.0  15.0  28.0
(0, 1, c)  16.0  17.0  18.0  33.0
(1, 0, a)  19.0  20.0  21.0  41.0
(1, 0, b)  22.0  23.0  24.0  46.0
(1, 0, c)  26.0  27.0  28.0  53.0
```

EDIT: Another possible problem is some values of third tuples not match:

```
print(df) 
              a     b     c
(0, 0, d)   1.0   2.0   3.0 <- d not match
(0, 0, e)   4.0   5.0   6.0 <- e not match
(0, 0, c)   7.0   8.0   9.0
(0, 1, a)  10.0  11.0  12.0
(0, 1, b)  13.0  14.0  15.0
(0, 1, c)  16.0  17.0  18.0
(1, 0, a)  19.0  20.0  21.0
(1, 0, b)  22.0  23.0  24.0
(1, 0, c)  26.0  27.0  28.0

#get values of third level
s = df.index.str[2]
#dict of not matched values 
new = dict.fromkeys(np.setdiff1d(s, df.columns), np.nan)
print (new)
{'d': nan, 'e': nan}
```

---

```
#added new columns used for lookup
df1 = df.assign(**new)
print (df1)
              a     b     c   d   e
(0, 0, d)   1.0   2.0   3.0 NaN NaN
(0, 0, e)   4.0   5.0   6.0 NaN NaN
(0, 0, c)   7.0   8.0   9.0 NaN NaN
(0, 1, a)  10.0  11.0  12.0 NaN NaN
(0, 1, b)  13.0  14.0  15.0 NaN NaN
(0, 1, c)  16.0  17.0  18.0 NaN NaN
(1, 0, a)  19.0  20.0  21.0 NaN NaN
(1, 0, b)  22.0  23.0  24.0 NaN NaN
(1, 0, c)  26.0  27.0  28.0 NaN NaN


#used df1 for sum and lookup
df['new'] = df1.sum(axis=1) - df1.lookup(df1.index, s)
print (df)
              a     b     c   new
(0, 0, d)   1.0   2.0   3.0   NaN
(0, 0, e)   4.0   5.0   6.0   NaN
(0, 0, c)   7.0   8.0   9.0  15.0
(0, 1, a)  10.0  11.0  12.0  23.0
(0, 1, b)  13.0  14.0  15.0  28.0
(0, 1, c)  16.0  17.0  18.0  33.0
(1, 0, a)  19.0  20.0  21.0  41.0
(1, 0, b)  22.0  23.0  24.0  46.0
(1, 0, c)  26.0  27.0  28.0  53.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Doest work, I copy the error message:

```
 `    df['new'] = df.sum(axis=1) - df.lookup(df.index, df.index.str[2])
  File ".........", line 3713, in lookup
    raise KeyError('One or more column labels was not found')
  KeyError: 'One or more column labels was not found'
```

`

I copy Index print:

```
`print(df.columns) 
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c']],
            codes=[[0, 1, 2]])
print(df.index)
Index([(0.0, 0.0, 'a'), (0.0, 0.0, 'b'), (0.0, 0.0, 'c'), (0.0, 1.0, 'a'), (0.0, 1.0, 'b'), (0.0, 1.0, 'c'), (0.0, 2.0, 'a'), (0.0, 2.0, 'b'), (0.0, 2.0, 'c'), (1.0, 0.0, 'a'), (1.0, 0.0, 'b'), (1.0, 0.0, 'c'), (1.0, 1.0, 'a'), (1.0, 1.0, 'b'), (1.0, 1.0, 'c'), (1.0, 2.0, 'a'), (1.0, 2.0, 'b'), (1.0, 2.0, 'c'), (2.0, 0.0, 'a'), (2.0, 0.0, 'b'), (2.0, 0.0, 'c'), (2.0, 1.0, 'a'), (2.0, 1.0, 'b'), (2.0, 1.0, 'c'), (2.0, 2.0, 'a'), (2.0, 2.0, 'b'), (2.0, 2.0, 'c')], dtype='object')
print(df.index.str[2])
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')`
```

I hope It could help me